# JPA Criteria Expression Replace Character

Tags: expression, jpa-criteria

In type `String` to replace all `-` with `*` I can write

```
String firstName = firstName.replaceAll("-", "*");
```

Is there a way to do the same in `Criteria Expression`?

I need to remove special characters from the first name before comparing it to the pattern in `like` method.

My expression:

```
Expression<String> firstName = root.get("firstName");
builder.like(firstName, pattern);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain why you want to change the column name?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I don't want to change the column name. I just want to remove any special character in the returned firstName

Comment: I see but then you have to do that in the result. The Expression is for building the query.. What's the result of you query'

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have updated the post. I need to replace the characters before I run the query.

Comment: where do you want to replace the characters? In the column in the database?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli just in the search. For example, if my last name in the database is `Al-haddad` I want to remove the `-` in my query just for the comparing, I don't want to really change my last name value in the database itself.

Comment: the you must use a function on the field: Have a look here http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/query-that-uses-String-REPLACE-function-td6344747.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SimonMartinelli comment. My issue is solved by using

```
builder.function("REGEXP_REPLACE", String.class, firstName, builder.literal("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+"), builder.literal(""));
```